# Accessing 2d array elements with pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Can someone explain why this program is printing "v" as output? I understand that the commented part of the code is used to access the 3rd char of the 2nd string, but how does the first one work?

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> int main(void)
> {
> static char a[3][5] = {"axcd", "efgh","ijkl"};
> putchar (*(*a+1)-2);
> // putchar (*(*(a+1))+2);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should initialize a 2D array by double brackets, i.e

```
static char arr[2][3] = {{"a","b","c"},{"e","f","g"}};
```

To access, for example, "g" which is in the **second** row and **third** column we use:

```
*(arr + (1 * 3 + 2));
```

'arr' is address in the memory where the array is stored.
'1' is the index of the wanted row, '3' is the length of each row (==number of columns).
'2' is the index of the element we want in the appropriate row.

In the general case to get an element in row i and column j we use:

```
int arr[N][M], i, j;
... //set values for i, j..
*(arr + (i*M + j));
```